# redirection using script parameters in bash

Tags: bash, unix

edit: thank you I think that syntax wise the script is now running ok.

My script takes 4 parameters:

1. log_file_name
2. program_name
3. input_file_name
4. output_file_name

I want to redirect the input file into the program (in c) and then redirect the output into the log file.
then check differences with the desired given output file (parameter 4).
what is the  most elegant way to do this?

I tried the following code which didn't work-

```
#!/bin/bash
$2.c < $3 > $1 
var = `diff $1 $4`
if  [[ var=="" ]]
then echo "Out files match"
exit 0
fi
echo "Out files mismatch"
exit 1
```

I have another script which compiles the .c file beforehand

```
#!/bin/bash

gcc -Wall -o $2 $2.c &> $1
var=`grep -e warnings -e errors $1`
if [[ $var == "" ]]
then echo "Compile succeeded"
exit 0
fi
echo "Compile failed"
exit 1
```

Comment: Too many wrong/weird things at once. Can you show us your script? It is not clear at all what are you exactly doing. Redirections seems good, but I'm not sure about the vars. Also, you compiled your program, right?

Comment: yes I have another script which runs the program through gcc

Comment: Verify your script via https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Assuming your compiled program is `$2.c`, your redirections are OK. You have some issue in the `var` assignation. Run your script through shellcheck.net as told. BTW, why do you say it is not working? Errors? Behavior?

Comment: I have another script which runs this script and the i recive errors from current script
I ran through shellcheck and seems like i forgot  $ before var in the comparison (inside the if) and also had spare spaces around = (var = )

Comment: In bash, You can use *process substitution*, e.g. `$2.c < <($3) > $1`  where `< <($3)` is the process substitution taking the output of your program and redirecting it as if you were reading from the file. If you don't need the redirection and simply want the output to be treated as a file, then `<($3)` will do.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
var=`diff  $1 $4`
if  [[ $var == "" ]];then
    echo "Out files match"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Out files mismatch"
    echo " < : Actual output "
    echo " > : Excepted output "
    diff $1 $4 | grep -v "^---" | grep -v "^[0-9c0-9]"
    exit 1
fi

Try above code to difference between output log and actual output
```